# Сложноподчинённое предложение или сложносочинённое? Или вообще комбинированный вид? Правильно ли составлен тест?

Tags: лексика

При поступлении у меня возник вопрос и я подала на апелляцию. Пожалуйста, помогите!

> Мы знали, что Петька принес двух худых карасей, но молчали.

Какого вида это предложение?
а) СПП с изъяснительным;
б) СПП со сравнительным оборотом;
в) СПП следствия;
г) ССП.

Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: Интеренсно,а пункт г) зачем тут?

Answer (score 1):

Мы знали, что Петька принес двух худых карасей, но молчали.

**Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным,** которое относится к первому сказуемому в главном предложении.

Главное предложение: Мы знали, но молчали. Однородные сказуемые связаны противительным союзом НО.